# Test if every element of an array is in another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have two arrays, `x` and `y`, where `y` is a subset of `x`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [3, 4, 7]
```

I want to return an array like:

```
ret = [False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]
```

If `y` were just a single number it would be easy enough (`x == y`), but I tried the equivalent `x in y` and it didn't work. Of course, I could do it with a for loop, but I'd rather there was a neater way.

I've tagged this Pandas since `x` is actually a Pandas series (a column in a dataframe). `y` is a list, but can be made to be a NumPy array or Series if needed.

Comment: `ret = [num in y for num in x]`

Comment: Since you tagged pandas, I've closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [3, 4, 7]
print([x in y for x in x])
```

Comment: (ab)using `x` like that (`for x in x`) is not recommended. There are many more letters to choose from. xD

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I like it.  "(ab)using".  Nice!

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
s = pd.Series(x)
s.isin(y)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool
```

And to return list:

```
s.isin(y).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Intersection can also do this for you.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,9,11,15]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
c = [True if x in list(set(a).intersection(b)) else False for x in a]

print(c)
```